# I have a rogue span class that's appearing and it's breaking a link

Tags: css, href

I'm trying to figure out where it's populating from and how do i get rid of it so the link works again.

Simple sharing of social links on my website. All the links are suppose to be like so:

```
<div class="share_links sogreen">
    <span class="st_pinterest_custom">
        <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={path='recipe/{url_title}'}{if recipe_photo}&media={recipe_photo}{/if}" target="_blank" class="pinterest upper social-share">Pinterest</a>
    </span>
    <span class="st_facebook_custom">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={path='recipe/{url_title}'}" target="_blank" class="facebook upper social-share">Facebook</a>
    </span>
    <span class="st_twitter_custom">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/share?text={title}&url={path='recipe/{url_title}'}" target="_blank" class="twitter upper social-share">Twitter</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I've added a screen shot to show how pinterest is adding an extra  class in the first link.

[image]

I've highlighted the extra span in chrome inspect elemnt.

Comment: The `span` is being added through JavaScript by the Pinterest script. The only way to prevent the `span` from being added would be to remove the Pinterest script, or remove the classes the script is using to target the element - `pinterest upper social-share`. Which will make the button stop working, probably.

Comment: Looks to me like that span is being auto-generated by a plugin or something. Based on the class name I would assume this plugin or library is called "pinit". What sort of system is this on? Wordpress? Squarespace? Custom? The answer would depend on that. As another user pointed out, you could try removing the `pinterest` or other classes from the link and see if that causes it to stop being picked up by this library/plugin.

Comment: @ßßß it's on magento

Comment: @BrettDeWoody the button doesn't work as is...

Comment: So remove this script? <script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>